# Definition of the term 'parastatics' specific to physics and math for physics

Tags: definition

The biological definition of 'parastatics' is closest to the general one: relating to mimicry between adjacent species. There is likewise a systems definition regarding one system compensating for a weakness in another. And there is a genetic definition. The noun is also used: 'parastasis'.

I first noticed the term in a 60-year-old Polish text (*parastatyce*) where the reference is to relativity or the quantum.

But although I see the term in physics and math-for-physics abstracts (for example) I cannot find a definition. Google search is somewhat 'contaminated' by the presence of a band of this name. (Just as: searchers for data on 'ceramite' will have to negotiate endless references to a fantasticated material of the same name in a certain gaming universe. Plus what seems to be a trademark issue.)

Comment: Parasitic number? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_number

Comment: Also, parasitic drag; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_drag

Comment: Seen where? Which reference? Which page?

Comment: Thanks Henry. Appreciated. Would you say the following also expressed a typo? https://www.math.sissa.it/seminar/remarkable-algebra-connected-combinatorics-and-parastatics

Comment: @GDugdale - probably.  Try [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Yoneda+algebra%22+parastatics) in which that link appears

Answer (score 6):

I suspect in Physics it is a typo for [*parastatistics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parastatistics), let through by the spell checker because of the biological usage

Take for example https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207085 where *parastatics* appears in the abstract but not in the article or references, while *parastatistics* appears three times in the article and three times in the references

Comment: Furthermore, [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sami-Muslih/publication/226209983_Riesz_Fractional_Derivatives_and_Fractional_Dimensional_Space/links/56cd643008ae4d8d64978373/Riesz-Fractional-Derivatives-and-Fractional-Dimensional-Space.pdf) and [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Eqab-Rabei/publication/228613295_Fractional_dimensional_harmonic_oscillator/links/0912f507e87ba5d8cc000000/Fractional-dimensional-harmonic-oscillator.pdf), which share Muslih as an author, both mention "parastatics" but cite a paper on parastatistics, for example.